# Usage of ゃ で, when buying countable nouns

Tags: conjunctions

> パン屋{や}でパンを買{か}います。

Not sure what ゃ で means here. Noun, ゃ で, noun.

Comment: the downvotes seem a bit harsh. for the beginner the mixture of kanas, kanji, and furigana can potentially make parsing word boundaries difficult.

Answer (score 2):

From the edit history, the source seems to be this image.
[image]

The furigana seems quite small, so this might explain why you *thought* it should have been written as

> パン**ゃで**

However,

1. 1. ゃで
   2. やで

are not the same thing. It should actually be 1.2, **やで**, with a regular sized や. 1.1, with the small や, by itself suggests that there should have been a [youon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C5%8Don) before で. For example (not pertaining to the given image)

2. 1. かい**しゃ**で
   2. でん**しゃ**で

That is why the title might be considered misleading. With the regular sized  や, it is expected that
やで could make sense.

In the given image, ～や (～屋, regular や）is a suffix that means *shop*. So *bread shop* → *bakery*. In this case, で marks the location where an action takes place. So the given image reads, more or less, *I buy bread at the bakery.* Two more examples

3. 1. 本屋｛ほんや｝で本｛ほん｝を買{か｝います。
      *I buy books at the bookstore.*
   2. 図書館｛としょかん｝で勉強｛べんきょう｝します。
      *I study at the library.*

Answer (score 1):

パン屋{や} is one word and means bakery. パン屋{や}で means "at the bakery".

Comment: Maybe you can give other examples of ～屋, so that OP can see it's a common way of referring to a particular type of shop.

Comment: @Earthliŋ when i can get to a proper keyboard, sure. :-)